# To create a gridview and update the table with the given details

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

i'm looking to update the details given by user such as name,address..etc in a table and also to show in the gridview.

so that i can edit/update in the gridview itself

```
string s = Session["something"].ToString();
            string str=string.Empty;

        //bool bNextResult;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=AMRNDHW1995\\DEV1;UID=POMS_ZOETIS_D_RO;PWD=12Werty@; database=POMS_Zoetis_D;");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select amount from budget_detail where year='" + s + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);



        //DataSet ds =new DataSet();
        //da.Fill(ds);


        //while (bNextResult == true)
        //{

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            str += dr.GetValue(0).ToString()               
                +"\n";
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow DR = dtTable.NewRow();
DR["Name"]=TxtName.Text;
DR["Age"]=TxtAge.Text;
DR["Place"]=TxtPlace.Text;
dtTable.adtTable.Rows.Add(DR);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTable;
```